# C# WCF service host question

Tags: c#, deployment, wcf

I have a C# WCF service DLL that gets hosted by WcfSvcHost.exe when I debug.  I would like to deploy this onto a machine nearby.  What do I use to host this dll on the machine that I want to deploy it to?

Could someone point me to the needed documentation?

I know you can build the service as a .exe and make it self hosting, but I'd rather not do that.

Is there some way to make a windows service based on this WCF dll?
I also do not want to use IIS because the target machine might not have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few really good articles out there - basically, it's really simple: you need some config for your WCF service, and a `ServiceHost` instance which hosts your service class (that implements the service contract) - and that's about it!

Check out these resources:

- [Hosting WCF Services](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0701041&page=3)
- [WCF Essentials: Self-Hosting](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/WCF-Essentials/Hosting/)
- [Configurating Host base addresses in WCF](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/07/13/31879.aspx)

Should help a bit - otherwise come back and ask more specifically, if you have problems!

Marc

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a Windows Service project and host your services there. Keep in mind you have to set the url, open the services and so on, stuff you don't need to do while hosting them on a IIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an wpf application to host it: http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/